# Is there any way to force a ManyToMany relationship behaves as ManyToOne?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have this two entities `Command` and `Predetermined` and they are related as `ManyToMany`:

```
class Command
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use ActiveTrait;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var Predetermined[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Predetermined", mappedBy="commands", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $predetermined;

    ...
}

class Predetermined
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use ActiveTrait;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=160)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $smsText;

    /**
     * @var Command[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Command", inversedBy="predetermined", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="predetermined_has_command")
     */
    private $commands;

    ...
}
```

Is there any way, using a form (is the only one I am seeing here) to change how they behaves? Take a look to the pics below:

[image: 2016-01-27_22-57-56]

I allow here to choose many commands which is why I used a `ManyToMany` but ...

[image: 2016-01-27_22-58-11]

in this one I doesn't so I still need to use same entities but change the behavior at form level. Can any give me some help on this? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want allow multiple choices in the first and restrict to one in the second form ?

Comment: @chalasr yes, you got it! That's exactly what I want

Comment: Do you have a FormType (or use of FormBuilder in the method displaying the form) ? If yes, please add it in your question

Comment: @chalasr no I don't have. I am using EasyAdminBundle but the principle is the same I just need to see how to achieve this using a Form and then I can implement as EasyAdmin does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally use the `multiple` attribute in your FormBuilder's field, like

```
$builder->add('commands', 'entity', array(
    'class'     => 'YourBundle:Command',
    'multiple'  => yourCondition ? true : false,
));
```

I've found the EasyAdminBundle way from this [PR](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/pull/337), you should be able to use the following

```
// app/config/admin/entities/YourEntity
fields:
    - { property: 'commands', multiple: false }
```

For one form, and set it to false for another.
Or you can define a parameter like :

```
- { property: 'commands', multiple: %condition% }
```

Comment: That makes sense, I will try and come back with test results, thanks

Comment: I don't know EasyAdminBundle, but it works in SonataAdmin (which uses the symfony FormBuilder)

Comment: Yup, you're right, that allow to define the selection to be many but what about when I need to choose one? [Here](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/tutorials/customizing-admin-controller.md#customize-the-form-used-to-create-new-entities) is the docs but I am not sure how to override the form. Also I am not following on your latest update

Comment: Set multiple to false doesn't restrict the maximum choice to one ? Also you can use a parameter like in my last edit, and set it dynamically using your condition

Comment: Hmmm ... are you defining the type of your field ? Maybe you have to specify type `choice` for use the `multiple` attribute ? Or `entity`

Comment: if I do that I get this error: `The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.`

Comment: Last try ... using type `entity` ? (I think it's used by default but I hope no)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102041/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-chalasr).